# How to read CSV with few text lines at the top using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have CSV files that look like this:

```
Data Export
Export type:;Real Sensor History Plot
Date of export:;12/20/2021 7:26:33 PM
Sensor name:;AD_St

TimeStamp;Distance [m];Strain [us]
12/17/2021 12:03:34 AM;295.7393;99.73
12/17/2021 12:03:34 AM;295.9945;63.162
12/17/2021 12:03:34 AM;296.2498;40.102
```

How to read this file starting with the structured data? from :

```
 TimeStamp;Distance [m];Strain [us]
```

So far I have tried:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: also, that doesn't look like a normal CSV file to me, though I could be wrong. is it normal to have multiple column headers in a CSV file?

Comment: @rv.kvetch df=pd.read_csv(file)

Comment: Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), there's a `header` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
pandas.read_csv('file_path',header=X)
```

and replace `X` with the number of rows you want to skip to reach the row with the col headers/names. Pandas automatically skips empty lines.

Comment: That works. Thanks